# What should the Hijab for Muslim women cover?

Tags: hijab, modesty

I'm asking this since there's a range of "coverage" that we see in Muslim women, from the niqab which covers everything except for the eyes to a headscarf that covers just the head and not the neck/chest area, and other variations.

Answer (score 12):

It is mandatory that women wear cloths that cover their whole bodies.  But since this question is about Hijab.  Allah tells us in the Qur'an:

> وَقُل لِّلۡمُؤۡمِنَـٰتِ يَغۡضُضۡنَ مِنۡ أَبۡصَـٰرِهِنَّ وَيَحۡفَظۡنَ
> فُرُوجَهُنَّ وَلَا يُبۡدِينَ زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا مَا ظَهَرَ مِنۡهَا‌ۖ
> وَلۡيَضۡرِبۡنَ بِخُمُرِهِنَّ عَلَىٰ جُيُوبِہِنَّ‌ۖ وَلَا يُبۡدِينَ
> زِينَتَهُنَّ إِلَّا لِبُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوۡ ءَابَآٮِٕهِنَّ أَوۡ
> ءَابَآءِ بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوۡ أَبۡنَآٮِٕهِنَّ أَوۡ أَبۡنَآءِ
> بُعُولَتِهِنَّ أَوۡ إِخۡوَٲنِهِنَّ أَوۡ بَنِىٓ إِخۡوَٲنِهِنَّ أَوۡ
> بَنِىٓ أَخَوَٲتِهِنَّ أَوۡ نِسَآٮِٕهِنَّ أَوۡ مَا مَلَكَتۡ
> أَيۡمَـٰنُهُنَّ أَوِ ٱلتَّـٰبِعِينَ غَيۡرِ أُوْلِى ٱلۡإِرۡبَةِ مِنَ
> ٱلرِّجَالِ أَوِ ٱلطِّفۡلِ ٱلَّذِينَ لَمۡ يَظۡهَرُواْ عَلَىٰ عَوۡرَٲتِ
> ٱلنِّسَآءِ‌ۖ وَلَا يَضۡرِبۡنَ بِأَرۡجُلِهِنَّ لِيُعۡلَمَ مَا
> يُخۡفِينَ مِن زِينَتِهِنَّ‌ۚ وَتُوبُوٓاْ إِلَى ٱللَّهِ جَمِيعًا
> أَيُّهَ ٱلۡمُؤۡمِنُونَ لَعَلَّكُمۡ تُفۡلِحُونَ (٣١)

Translation (interpretation of meaning):

> And say to the believing women that they should lower their gaze and
> guard their modesty; that they should not display their beauty and
> ornaments except what (ordinarily) appear thereof; that they should
> draw their veils over their bosoms and not display their beauty except
> to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons,
> their husbands' sons, their brothers, or their brothers' sons, or
> their sisters' sons, or their women, or the slaves whom their right
> hands possess or male servants free of physical needs, or small
> children who have no sense of the shame of sex; and that they should
> not strike their feet in order to draw attention to their hidden
> ornaments. And O ye Believers! Turn ye all together towards Allah that
> ye may attain Bliss. (31)

Surat 24 Ayah  31

From this Ayah we get that Women should at least have the Hijab covering their heads to as the Ayah says, bosoms.

> [Abu Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/34/85) narrates:
>
> Asma, daughter of AbuBakr, entered upon the Messenger of Allah
> (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) wearing thin clothes. The Messenger of
> Allah (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) turned his attention from her. He
> said: O Asma', when a woman reaches the age of menstruation, it does
> not suit her that she displays her parts of body except this and this,
> and he pointed to her face and hands.
>
> graded as Saheeh

Comment: It's the hadith from Abu Dawud on the "possible dupe" question: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-does-islam-say-about-womens-clothing

Comment: Could you clarify the implications of that hadith on the issue of covering the neck and chest area?

Comment: @shoehada sorry I do not understand.

Comment: Some hijab styles just cover the hair and not the neck and chest area.

Comment: @shoehada oh, well the Ayah clearly states to cover to your bosoms.  And the Hadith states that the only things that is ok showing is the face and hands.  So these kinds of Hijabs are not following the Ayah or the hadith, and I have my doubts about the way some people wear the hijabs that show their hair.

Comment: Not that I doubt the Ayah or the Hadith, but english is a limited language so I don't know how articulate the translation is; could you elucidate on: *they should not display their beauty and ornaments except what (**ordinarily**) appear thereof* and *that they should draw their veils over their bosoms and not display their beauty except to their husbands*. Here does Bosom mean chest, torso, upper chest, neck?

Comment: @Pureferret that would be a good question for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Allah says in the Holy Quran Chapter 33 Surah Al Ahzaab verse 59:

> O Prophet!  Tell your wives and daughters, and the women of the
>   believers, that they should cast their outer garments over their
>   persons.  It is expected that they will be recognized and that they
>   will not be molested.   And Allah is Oft Forgiving, Most Merciful.

Allah says in the Holy Quran Chapter 24 Surah An-Noor verse 31:

> And O Prophet, enjoin the believing women to restrain their gaze and guard
>   their private parts and not to display their adornment except that
>   which is displayed of itself (their face and hands), and to draw their
>   veils over their bosoms and not to display their adornment except
>   before their husbands, their fathers, the fathers of their husbands,
>   their sons and the sons of their husbands, their brothers, their
>   brothers sons, their sisters’ sons,  their female associates, and
>   those in their possession and male attendants incapable of sexual
>   desire,  and those boys who have not yet attained knowledge of sexual
>   matters.   Also forbid them to stamp their feet on the ground lest
>   their hidden ornaments should be displayed.

You can infer from the second para that Hijab should cover a woman from head to bosom. But it doesn't mean that it stops at the bosom. Hijab goes till toes.

Comment: the Hijab does not go all the way to the toes :)  You see, a women can wear a modest shirt a skirt and a Hijab and still be very modest.

Comment: I dont think women can wear a skirt and a Hijab. wearing skirt is prohibited in Islam.Do you have any citation which says islam permits wearing skirt

Comment: What kind of skirt are we talking about? Long skirt, short skirt, miniskirt?

Comment: I am talking about long skirt if it goes till toes. and is wide enough not to reveal curves

Comment: That is what I am talking about to.

Comment: How is wearing a long skirt not permissible? Aren't jilbabs essentially long dresses/skirts?

Comment: @shoehada we mean wearing long skirt is permisisble provided it goes till toes. and is wide enough not to reveal curves

Comment: @shoehada If you ask how early scholars defined Jilbaab: Abu Su'ood said : " The jilbaab is a garment that is wider than a khimaar but less than a ridaa (outer-cloak). A woman wraps it around her head and leaves hanging what falls to her breast..."

Comment: @Ershad I was referring to the jilbab in today's context: The modern jilbāb covers the entire body, except for hands, face, and head. The head and neck are then covered by a scarf or wrap (khimar). Some women will also cover the hands and face (niqab). (via http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jilb%C4%81b)

Comment: @refhat I was mentioned the long skirt since you said that wearing skirt is prohibited in Islam.

Answer (score 0):

This relevant to the Twelver Shiite school.

An adult/pubescent lady can only keep her face and hands
*uptil* the wrist uncovered while observing
the Islam Hijab. Otherwise every part of her body should be
covered, including the hair.

To elaborate, face here includes the region between the forehead (included), and the area below the chin that is visible when a
headscarf is worn (not the neck). And does not include the ears.
No part of the arms should be left uncovered.

From Grand Ayatullah Sayyid Ali Husaini Sistani:

> **Question**: A vast majority of Muslim women who observe hijãb are used to keeping their chins and a small part of the under chin exposed but they cover the neck. Is this permissible for them? And how big an area of the face women can expose? And are the ears included in that?
>
> **Answer**: The ears are not part of the face, therefore it is obligatory to cover them. As for the part of the chin and the under chin that are seen when putting on the common head scarf, it is to be considered as part of the face.

[Women's issues » Questions and Answers](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/46/2066/)

> A woman should not show her beauty or adornments except what appears by uncontrolled factors such as the wind blowing her clothes

[Question & Answer » Hijab (Islamic Dress)](http://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01208/)