# Can you give verses in the quran about hijab and veli?

Tags: hijab

Can you give verses in the quran about hijab and veli?

Comment: IMO you can easily research this on your own with a simple google search. [24:30](https://quran.com/24/30),
[24:31](https://quran.com/24/31),
[24:60](https://quran.com/24/60),
[33:33](https://quran.com/33/33),
[33:53](https://quran.com/33/53),
[33:55](https://quran.com/33/55),
[33:59](https://quran.com/33/59) are all on hijab.

Comment: The following posts already cover your inquiry [Is there any specific ayah in the coran to oblige wearing of hijab](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35627/is-there-any-specific-ayah-in-the-coran-to-oblige-the-wearing-of-hijab), [What verses of the qur'an urge veiling for men women and what is the justification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23703/what-verses-of-the-quran-urge-veiling-for-men-women-and-what-is-the-justificat) and some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You need to read Tafseer and Hadith for better understand those verses***

**About hijab there are one more Ayah**

O Prophet, tell your wives and your daughters and the women of the believers to bring down over themselves [part] of their outer garments. That is more suitable that they will be known and not be abused. And ever is Allah Forgiving and Merciful..

***Surah Al Ahzab, 33: 59 [link](https://qurano.com/en/33-al-ahzab/verse-59/)***

Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.

***Sura An Nur  24:30 [link](https://qurano.com/en/24-an-nur/verse-30/)***

O children of Adam, We have bestowed upon you clothing to conceal your private parts and as adornment. But the clothing of righteousness - that is best. That is from the signs of Allah that perhaps they will remember.

***Sura Al A'raf , 7 : 26 [link](https://qurano.com/en/7-al-a-raf/verse-26/)***

Answer (score 0):

Verse 31 of Surah Noor is known as the verse of Hijab. It is said that with the revelation of this verse, hijab became obligatory on women.
And say to the believing lower their gaze and preserve representative vaginally and Ebdane adornments except what appeared to them and beating their necks on bosoms and Ebdane adornments except to their husbands or fathers ... and Aadharbn Borgelhn to know what they hide of their adornment )31(

And say to the believing women: "Shut up your eyes and purify yourselves, and do not reveal your ornaments except what is evident from it." And they should put their headscarves around their necks, and not reveal their ornaments except to their husbands or fathers ...; And do not stamp their feet to reveal what is hidden from their adornment.
Verse 59 of Surah Al-Ahzab also speaks of hijab, which is known as verse "Jilbab". In it, women are asked to cover themselves with jilbab. [12] Linguists have defined jilbab as a garment larger than a scarf and smaller than a robe, which women wear over their heads and cover up to their chests.

Ref: https://fa.wikishia.net/view/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D9%87_%D8%AD%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%A8