# Is it very sinful to not wear hijab?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, shirk, hijab

I dress decently but I don't wear hijab because I'm not ready for it. Is not wearing hijab makes me a bad Muslim or increases my sin?

Comment: See: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/763/what-should-the-hijab-for-muslim-women-cover Hijab is an obligation, and obligation means not doing it is sinful.

Answer (score 1):

Hijab is an obligatory act. Allah has commanded believing women to cover. It is sinful to neglect obligatory action.

Following links might provide better explanation.

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/7436/will-a-woman-who-does-not-wear-hijaab-go-to-hell

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/47569/is-hijab-compulsory-in-islam

https://abukhadeejah.com/the-niqab-for-the-muslim-woman-uncovering-her-face-and-hands-and-displaying-her-beautifications/