# Are women required to cover their face and palms in Islam?

Tags: women, hijab, islamic-countries

While there is also [another related question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/763/what-should-the-hijab-for-muslim-women-cover) on the website, my question is however different:

In many countries, Muslim women don't cover their face and palms, although they cover their hair, ears, neck, the parts of hand higher than wrist, and their body by Hijab.

There are also some Islamic countries that women cover their face with Hijab. Is it part of Islam or it's just a cultural issue of that countries? Is it a must? And if it is not a must in Islam, doesn't it limit the social activity of women in that countries?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why scholars disagree on whether it's obligatory for women  to veil their faces or not in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/why-scholars-disagree-on-whether-its-obligatory-for-women-to-veil-their-faces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very divisive issue that has been debated (and is still being debated) to death. Almost all of Islamic scholars agree that covering the hair is mandatory, but on covering the face you will find very little consensus. Those who believe that covering the face is mandatory have cited their interpretation of Quran and Hadith, while those who oppose them have their own interpretation as well. The answers in this [related question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2474/why-scholars-disagree-on-whether-its-obligatory-for-women-to-veil-their-faces/2496#2496) should shed more light on the subject.

Comment: Although one can relate covering of head directly from a verse in Quran but still covering your head in a way that no hair should be visible seems like going on extreme side. It requires much more effort and opposes "balance" and "Deen e Fitrat" (religion of Nature) guidelines

Answer (score 1):

While you will find verses in Quran that talk about women covering their head (hair, ears) and necks, I never read (or heard about) any verse talking about them covering their faces and palms.

I think for this part, is rather cultural (most coming from Middle East) or from zealous interpretations.

Answer (score -1):

Are women required to cover their face and palms in Islam? 
This is for here safely 100%ز God does not want robbed of our freedom, but..
First, if a company Invented  machine are too expensive and complicated so there must be a user instruction booklet machine properly.
Allah did not force you to cost you this religion did not forcing you to apply the Islamic law only for you, a woman must cover the entire body except her palms and face from strangers men and This is to protect her honor , and safeguard the right of her husband.
Not every young man have enough money for the marriage and also people are not satisfied that to make a relationship with their girls and mother nor their sisters without a marriage contract,
And if a woman showed all her body so every man will flirt her and
also if a woman covered what she should the cover of her body and used the makeup just for her husband There will not be any man cheat on his wife , and the young man will think just in the marriage.