# Does a women have to cover her face with a veil?

Tags: hijab, modesty

I used to cover my face, but now I only cover everything but my face.  Do I have to cover my face? is there anything in the Quran and authentic Sunnah about covering the face? if so, than is there a punishment for not covering the face?

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq), in it is what you need to know about how things work here.  I have edited your question for clarity, if I have made a Mistake and taken out or make blur any part of your question, you are free to edit it any time.

Comment: Similar questions:[1](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5607/435), [2](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2474/435), [3](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/763/435), [4](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/88/435).