# Is there any islamic reason for wearing niqaab (veiling of the face)?

Tags: practical-islam, women, hijab

Culture has begun to mingle with tradition and religion until people assume they are one and the same. In a new course I have signed up to, we are required to wear niqab (veil our faces) in front of the imam - is there any ISLAMIC evidence for us having to do so?

I know we must wear hijab to protect our modesty but is there any Islamic evidence for having to veil our faces or is this just culture?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: [Similar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7513/does-a-women-have-to-cover-her-face-with-a-veil#comment15060_7513)