# Who are allowed to see the face of woman who uses face veil?

Tags: women, hijab

Is it permitted in Islam for my elder sister's son who is leaving with me to see the face of my wife who wear face veil? 
My elder sister’s son (11 years) is leaving with me but my concern is that can he see my wife face? My wife is using face veil.

Comment: can you elaborate your question and concerns jazakAllah

Comment: I don't remember the Quran mentioning that  women must wear face veils. I think they are mentioned in other texts, therefore in my opinion, if Allah hasn't ordered to wear face veils then seeing her face will **not** constitute a sin.

Comment: See also: "[Why scholars disagree on whether it's obligatory for women to veil their faces or not in Islam?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2474/9123)"

Answer (score 3):

```
                                       IN THE NAME OF ALLAH
```

According to your inquiry as you have asked that

> Those that are allowed in Islam to see the face of woman that uses
>   face veil

You ought to pay attention to some points such as:

- Firstly it is not wajib or mandatory to cover the face (by face veil,
  Borqah, pushia, and so forth).
- Secondly (according to Imam-Khomeini as a Shia scholar, and probably
  at least majority of other scholars that have inferred it from the
  holy Quran):  women must cover all of their bodies and hairs in front
  of non-mahram except their faces (roundness of the face, seemingly
  the front part of the face) and their hands from fingers to the wrist
  of the hands.
- Thirdly that son doesn’t seem to be at the puberty age, but it is
  declared as the viewpoint of many scholars such as Ayatollah Khamenei
  (as a Shia scholars) (and many other scholars) that based on
  Ehtiat-al-Wajib it is better for women to cover their bodies and
  hairs from the boys who are not at the age of the puberty, but can be
  at the age of Mamayezi (can recognize good and bad and lust…)

**Conclusion:**

As it pointed out, it is not considered as a wajib or mandatory act for women to cover their faces by Burghah, then it would not be haram if that son looks at her faces (without the intention of lust). On the whole, wearing borghah is considered as a good act (mustahab) not Wajib. Good luck.

---

**[Reference](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa27916) and more info. (I recommend you to read them) :**

[www.islamquest.net (Arabic)](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa11663)

And also this site [Arabic 2](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa4325)

[www.islamquest.net (In English)](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa11663)

Answer (score 0):

Is it permissible for you to accept adultery as a veil? Is it permissible for you to make use of it?
Banwan Bayad, opposite Nam Muharram, Tammam, Baden, even Mohai Khoud ra Bapushanand, and Bushandan Gardi, I took a picture and I did not see it. And the benefit of a veil and rubin is obligatory, and it is necessary to make a pilgrimage as a pilgrim.
Pushash Zen Dar opposite Namharam Bayad Beh Gonne-i Pashad K:
Yes - I cut my hair and I didn't do it with Payin (without Arish and visitor machines) Ashkar Nebashed.
Do-Pergistgiye ¬ha and zibayi ¬hai body zen, Ba Jud Poseiden An, Ashkar Nebashed.
Sah-Rang and the peculiarities of the fact that there is no nebashed ke bring a Canadian orientation and a positive movement of the two parties. (2)

(1)Ref: https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa21879#

(2)Ref: https://farsi.khamenei.ir/news-content?id=27847