# What is the sunnah in dressing for men?

Tags: sunnah, men, clothing

I have seen a queston about dressing for [women](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/88/what-does-islam-say-about-womens-clothing).

I need to know :

- What does Islam say about men's clothing?
- Is it permitted to wear t-shirt,jeans in public?
- Is it permitted to tuck-in the shirts?
- Most of our scholars wear jibbah for prayers, why?

Please, provide some references from hadiths.

Comment: please refer to this links: http://www.sunnah.org/fiqh/islamic_dress.htm

Answer (score 1):

Question 1) is a general one and hopefully got sufficient reply. I will try to answer the others:

**Question 2 & 3)** Yes, it is perfectly allowed to wear Jeans, T-Shirt and the like. Likewise, there is no problem in tucking your shirt into the pants, by default. The problem is when the pants are not loose enough to hide your 'awrah'. Now, the 'awrah' of the men essentially stretches from navel to the knees, but what is often overlooked by some people is the proper manner of concealing the 'awrah', which besides hiding these body parts with a cloth also include proper tailoring of the garment. That is, if the pants or trousers are so tight as to reveal what one should be concealing like the curves of thighs/buttocks or loose but sticking to the skin like an adhesive and thus outlining the inner structure. Eventually, some garments can be alright while you are standing but all revealing when you bend e.g. in Sujood. Therefore, all with the matter is relative to situations and a careful choice about one's dress is the way out.

**Question 3)** Hopefully, it is for the above reason, it is desirable to wear a long shirt reaching near to the knees like a '*kurta*' or 'milder' styles like long-tail 'plumber' shirt. In the same line, avoiding tucked-in shirts gives some degree of satisfaction to others, which for example in the Indian Subcontinent is also taken as a sign of humility. Cultural tendencies always tend to cast their influence. Hopefully, it is for the above reasons, scholars in the west too embrace this idea of greater modesty and prefer long *Jibba* over short coat.
And as a matter of fact, in such cases where a general ruling is not possible, most of the people are left with misconceptions and exaggerated conclusions.

> "I personally prefer a long shirt over a short or tucked-in, a Jeans
>   over other material, and a knee-length over all. Finding the right
>   pants almost always gives a tough time but it is worth it."

Comment: though this answer doesn't mention any reference, but shows a reasonable understanding in the subject matter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know:
Men's compulsory  hijab is to wear pants down the knees, that is, the knees shouldnt be visible. 
Yes you can wear Jeans and Tees in public as long as it doesn't have anything haram on them like band names, superheroes, cuss words, lyrics, faces, figures, etc. 
Yes it is permissible to tuck in the shirts 
Most of our scholars wear a Jubbah because it's Sunnah.

Answer (score -1):

fard: 
1.covering private parts

sunnah:
1. loose clothing
2. covering shoulders
3. dress stopping at shin region
4. covering head

anything anyone else tells you is mistaking culture for sunnah

evidence from hadith will be weak because saying the prophet wore xyz doesnt mean he wants you to wear it. eg:the prophet wearing nike shoes changes nothing about the ruling of nike shoes unless you are mashallah doing what ibn umar was doing.

Comment: The OP asked for references and your answer lacks references!

Answer (score -1):

as far as I know, men should cover their body as strictly as women. A proper way of dressing, covering your body, acceptable  by the society and that's all it needs.