# Is it permissible for to have hajib which makes her look attractive to the opposite sex and that is fashionable?

Tags: halal-haram, women, hijab

I have heard that women's hijab are not meant to turn into contemporary hijab fashion, because the hijab is meant to cover oneself so to avoid attention from the opposite sex.

Now a day the hijabs are beautified to a degree that it has started to loose its purpose and instead started to attract people's attention.

So I was wondering, is it permissible (halal/haram) to use these fashionable and attractive hijab clothings which come in a variety of colors, patterns, and styles?

Is it impermissible for a women to have hijab which make her more attractive?

NOTE: **covered** in this case means body is properly covered with proper clothing that is NOT revealing of one's body.

*Reference from Quran & Hadith required.*

Answer (score 3):

At first I want to introduce you some verses in Quran about Hijab:

1 . verses (30,31,33 and 60 ) of [An-Nur](http://tanzil.net/#24:1)

2 . verses ( 35 , 53 , 55 and 59 ) of [Al-Ahzab](http://tanzil.net/#33:1)

According to these verses, a woman should cover her body completely from men who are not Mahram.
Moreover in [35th](http://tanzil.net/#24:35) verse of An-Nur , God has emphasized that women should cover their ornaments from men who are not Mahram .thus we should wear dresses which do not attract men .

" Hazrat Fatemeh wore like that and she was happy that her father delegated the task of housekeeping in her house instead of going out and facing men . " (1)

So Chador is the best Hijab.

(1) : Majlesi , 1403 AH , 43/81

Comment: Adam, an attractive dress is a dress that show women bodies attractive , like tight clothes , for example wearing Support with a short skirt is not suitable at all

Answer (score 2):

I have consulted a knowledgeable brother with sound Aqidah.

He has informed me that as long as the dress is covered, "attract attention" is a subjective issue since the culture influence will play major role on how you dress and how much attention you will be attracted because of the difference of your dress and it does not need to be necessary to be considered "pretty" in one culture while not in the another. Also, the intention of one's dress should be meant to dress because it dressed for ONESELF's pleasure because its pretty for her own eyes.

Hope that helps lead to a even better answer with authentic reference and better understanding.

Comment: Dressing on the basis of oneself's pleasure is not a suitable criteria. this will lead to the problem you've mentioned. another criteria must be also considered.